# How to disable annoying Resharper 8.0.2 code completion?

Tags: resharper, intellisense, code-completion

In my class, i have a private method Log(). When I want to use log(in that same class), I type 'Log' and then when I type '(', it automatically code complete the code as something else. I tried using visual studio intellisense instead of resharper but this wrong code completion still happens. Do I have to uninstall resharper or is there anything else I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found so far is to disable '(' as code complete character. To do that(from resharper documentation):

To define symbols that do not invoke code completion

1. On the main menu, choose ReSharper | Options. The Options dialog box opens.
2. On the left pane of the dialog, click IntelliSense | Completing Characters.
3. On the right pane, you can define whether to complete on space or not. To do that, select or clear check boxes for C#, VB.NET or any other language.
4. To define symbols that should not invoke code completion, type them in text boxes for C#, VB.NET or any other language.
5. Click Save or Save To to apply changes.

Are there any better/elegant solution?

Thanks.

Edit.

Apparently, i realized that i forgot to put static keyword that's why intellisense doesn't recognized that Log().